# Not Able to Access Terms Under Custom Taxonomy Archive

Tags: theme-development, custom-taxonomy

Having a `Custom Taxonomy` called `movie-genres`

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie-genres', 'with_front' => true) );
 register_taxonomy( 'movie-genres', array( 'movies' ), $args );
```

And I have a WP template hierarchy for the `Taxonomy` and it's associated `Terms` like below

```
archive.php
archive-movie-genres.php

taxonomy.php
taxonomy-movie-genres.php
taxonomy-movie-genres-action.php
```

Now when navigating in the browser I am able to see the CPTs listed for term of action like this

```
domain.com/movie-genres/action
```

but when landing at `movie-genres` to get the all terms listed under this taxonomy like

```
domain.com/movie-genres/
```

I am getting the `404` page in return!

As you can see I have the `archive-movie-genres.php` and `taxonomy-movie-genres.php` created so can you please let me know why I am getting ended at `404`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404 is the expected behaviour.

You'll find no link to such a URL in the WordPress admin, there's no functions to generate that URL in code, and there is no possible template for such an archive, as shown in the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) documentation (`archive-movie-genres.php` is not a valid template). The path `/movie-genres` alone will not return anything in WordPress under normal circumstances.

All WordPress templates are based around [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/), and that loop is for looping over and displaying *posts*, not terms.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here
i found a solution to make a static page but
i dont want to use static page, i want to put it on my plugin, i need a function that say use this template if some one reached the parents links, something like showing all categories , ill do the query , i just need to say to wordpress that tempalte exist

Comment: the solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555505/wordpress-custom-template-page-for-a-parent-category-and-all-child-categories

Comment: This should be a comment