# Theme template file for a specific custom taxonomy

Tags: theme-development, custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy

Is it possible to create a template file specific for a custom taxonomy?

For example, I have `music` Custom Post Type and it has three taxonomies `artist`, `album`, and `genre`. So the hierarchy would be like this:

```
music               // custom post type
├── artist          // taxonomy
│   ├── snopdogg    // taxonomy content
│   ├── tupac
│   └── biggie
├── album
│   ├── greatest-hits
│   ├── murder-death-kill
│   └── all-is-well
└── genre
    ├── rap
    ├── hip-hop
    └── alternative
```

For the custom post type, I'll create a `single-music.php` for displaying the music alone, right?

And `taxonomy.php` for displaying the single taxonomy content like `rap`, `tupac`, `greatest-hits` right?

But what if I want to display `artist`, `album` and `genre`? For example, if want to display all `artist` on a page using the custom taxonomy `artist`?

What file should I add? or is it done manually? like, I will literally add a `page` called artist and then that's it? If yes, is there a way to automate it? Like how `single-post.php`, `taxonomy.php`, `archive.php` works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not Able to Access Terms Under Custom Taxonomy Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412495/not-able-to-access-terms-under-custom-taxonomy-archive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a file specific for custom taxonomy itself?

Yes, it's possible in WordPress.

> So for the custom post type (`music`) I'll create `single-music.php` for displaying the music alone right?

That is correct.

> and `taxonomy.php` for displaying the single taxonomy content/value like `rap`, `tupac`, `greatest-hits` right?

That is also right.

> but how about if I want to display `artist`, `album` and `genre`? Like If want to display all `artist` on a page using the custom taxonomy `artist`? What file should I add?

You can create different custom taxonomy template files based on the following file name priority convention. WordPress looks for these template files and uses the available file with the highest priority.

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php (highest priority for an individual custom taxonomy term. e.g. taxonomy-artist-snopdogg.php)
    │
    └──→ taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php (highest priority for a custom taxonomy archive. e.g. taxonomy-artist.php)
        │
        └──→ taxonomy.php
            │
            └──→ archive.php
                │
                └──→ index.php (lowest priority, this is used if no other template file is found)
```

For exampe, if the URL you are visiting is a custom taxonomy term URL of `artist` taxonomy, and `snopdogg` taxonomy term (e.g. `example.com/music-information/artist/snopdogg` [in this URL, `music-information` is just a custom url-prefix I've assumed for your custom taxonomies]), WordPress will look for `taxonomy-artist-snopdogg.php` file. If this file is not found, then WordPress will try to load `taxonomy-artist.php` file. If even this file is not found, then WordPress will keep trying to load other lower priority files until it reaches `index.php`.

Similarly, if the URL you are visiting is a custom taxonomy archive URL of `artist` taxonomy (e.g. `example.com/music-information/artist`), then WordPress will try to load the `taxonomy-artist.php` file.

So, if you want to display all available `artist` on the `artist` custom taxonomy archive page, you can create a file called `taxonomy-artist.php`, and use the [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function to retrieve all the terms associated with the taxonomy and display them on the page. For example:

```php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'artist',
    'hide_empty' => false,
);
$artists = get_terms($args);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($artists as $artist) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link($artist) . '">' . $artist->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

For more information, you may refer to the following links:

1. [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
2. [Taxonomy Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/)
3. [Custom Post Type Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/)

Comment: hi @Fayaz, thanks for the detailed answer, it did help me clarify some confusion before, now that there is taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php, is there anyway to automate it? instead of literally/manually creating a taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php?

Comment: Yes, of course. WordPress falls back to less specific template file if `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` is not available. So, you can simply create `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` and in that file query the current term and show data accordingly. You can do more generic implementation with just a single `taxonomy.php` to handle them all. But the more generic you go, the more condition you'll have to program to handle all possible cases within that template file.